# How to keep alive an object for later use in another function?

Tags: c++, object

I have a base class called `Mijloc_transport` and 2 derived classes called `Masina` and `Tramvai`. I must do an menu type program that can create different kind of objects from the derived classes and show them. I'm using the UPCASTING method and when I press 1 the `if(tasta=="1")` creates an object and I can see what type it is using:  `tabp[0]->show();`. It seems that when the program enters again in the do loop (using the main label), the object created as 1 is destroyed and I can't see `tabp[0]->show();` because the reference is deleted. What shall I do to keep the objects alive so I can put them in `tabp`?

```
Masina b(30);
p=&b;
tabp[i]=p;
```

so later I can display them....10x for your help

```
#include "include.hpp"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(void)
{    

    int i=0;

    Mijloc_transport *tabp[MAX];
    Mijloc_transport *p;

    int tasta;
main:
    do
    {
        //cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n";
        cout<<endl<<"apasa orice tasta pentru a reveni la meniu "<<endl; getch();
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Tasteaza numarul optiunii dorite din meniu:"<<endl; 
        cout<<"1. creaza o masina cu 30 cai putere"<<endl;      //create an Masina derived Oject
        cout<<"2. creaza un tramvai cu 20 de locuri"<<endl;//create an Tramvai derived Oject
        cout<<"3. afiseaza memoria"<<endl;                       //print the objects
        cout<<"4. iesire"<<endl;
        tasta=cin.get();
    }
    while(tasta!='1' && tasta!='2'&& tasta!='3'&& tasta!='4');


    if(tasta=='1')
    {
        Masina b(30);
        p=&b;
        tabp[i]=p;

        tabp[0]->show();

        cout<<endl<<"apasa orice tasta pentru a reveni la meniu "<<endl;
        getch();

        //i++;            //TREBUIE INCREMENTAT cand ai mai mult de un obiect
        goto main;
    }

    if(tasta=='3')
    {
        //afiseaza elementele din memorie
        //for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)                      //J<=i
        //tabp[j]->show();

        tabp[0]->show();
        cout<<endl<<"apasa orice tasta pentru a reveni la meniu "<<endl;
        getch();

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please at least try to translate your code, as everyone in here speaks English, but not everyone speaks your language.

Comment: So you are using `goto`. You should try to avoid that. You should probably put the part between the label and the `goto` into a function.

Comment: OMG, you want us to debug a C++ code featuring GOTOs???

Comment: I understand, I used only once the goto, to jump to the do wile, 10x for you advinces, peace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Masina b(30);
p=&b;
tabp[i]=p;
```

do:

```
tabp[i] = new Masina(30);
```

and do not forget to do:

```
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i )
{
    delete tabp[i];
}
```

When you no longer need tabp (before existing main).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating the object on the stack, like this:

```
Masina b(30);
```

you must create it dynamically, like this:

```
Masina *b = new Masina(30);
```

and furthermore, you should declare `Masina *b` somewhere outside the loop, so that it persists longer than the time you're in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to read your code, but based on your title I am guessing you want to create an object on the heap using the `new` keyword. This will allow you to create an object on the heap (as opposed to the stack) which will stay alive after a function exits, be warned you must clean up the memory associated with the allocation of `new`.

Comment: With all my respect thank you guys, an especial to Yoel, I solved the problem. It seems that if you create an object with new in the heap he will live longer, until you will delete it. Peace to all!

Comment: @ozzyinterface exactly objects on the heap (allocated with new) live until you delete them. Objects on the stack (simply declared) live until the end of the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
tabp[i] = new Masina(30);
```

but please... Each time you are using `goto` (especially like this) God kill a kitten.

Comment: Indeed. [A very cute kitten](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/or-this-kitten-gets-it.jpg).